# Unable to locate element by XPATH within iframe using selenium (python)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, iframe, selenium-chromedriver

I've been attempting to obtain the link of an image within an iframe, but have had no success. I've double checked my imports, and I have all the necessary ones for running the code. I switch to frame successfully, but any attempt to select an element within results with an error (Unable to locate element)

```
# working code
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//main[@class='Content-main']//div[1]/div/iframe"))
# not working code
img = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//html[@xmlns='http://something']/body/img")
```

I've heard XPATH cannot locate xmlns content, so I've also tried these methods to search within (after switching to the iframe of course):

```
img = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//html/body/img")
img = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//body/img")
img = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//img")
```

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <iframe id="activeImage">
            # document
                  <!DOCTYPE html>
                 <html xmlns="http://something">
                        <body>
                            <div> class="irrelevant"></div>
                            <img src="http://something2"></img>
                        </body>
                 </html>
            </iframe>
        </body>
</html>
```

I think the issue could be related to a !DOCTYPE within a !DOCTYPE
Thanks for your help in advance
Best

Comment: "Could you please provide the complete code along with the link to the website you are automating?

Comment: The website requires an admin login unfortunately.